# How can I use BIRT with a remote (http/https) data source that reqiures authentication?

Tags: birt

Is it possible to use BIRT with a remote (http/https) XML data source that requires authentication?

- Cookie based
- HTTP authentication
- SSL Client certificate

Any of the above would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use HTTP based authentication with a syntax:

```
http://username:password@hostname:portnumber/path
```

But anyway you can use scripted data source and construct a report via API. I.e. you can write a Java software that pass an authentication and get data, bind them to BIRT and generate output in BIRT internal or standard format (html,pdf,doc,xls etc.).

Comment: Thank you. Got it working with both HTTP Basic and Digest over HTTPS.